# Windows 10 Universal app: "The size of the notification group is too large"

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

When I call Toaster.Show it throws 0x803E0209 (WPN_E_GROUP_SIZE) "The size of the notification group is too large" exception.

I have no notification at all in the notification center.

I tried changing group name and tag but get the same error.

Comment: I do not found `Toaster.Show` method in UWP. Could you provide us an [mcve]

Comment: static readonly ToastNotifier Toaster = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();// this line raises exception
   Toaster.Show(new ToastNotification(toast.GetXml())
   {
    Group = toastDisplayName,
    Tag = tag
   });

Comment: What is the `toast` in your code? Do you mean XmlDocument? If so, it seems it return the string that we can not set it to the ToastNotification constructor.

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature not yet available on Anniversary update of Windows 10. In the Creators update the length will be upgraded to 64 characters but for now it is limited to 16.

Reference: [Windows Developer Feedback](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/8629408-max-length-of-toast-tag-not-enough-for-a-simple-gu)